# HTML full width video with max-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I have the following problem:

[image]

I want to make a video header in HTML. The video should be 100% in width and exactly 400px in height. But on mobiles the video should be as hight as the source file.

My problem: when i set the max-height of the video to 400, the width also gets smaller.
But if the video width is smaller than 100% of the body width, the video should be 100% of width an slicks behind the border of the showed area...
then the vertical align should be center. 
(javascript is possible)

Please help me; I don't found good results on the internet.

Comment: Surely you have some code to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Instead of using max-height for desktop use min-height.
- For mobile try media queries to resize the video header to your
  needs!

[Details of min-height attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp)

[For Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)